# Error python datetime/time imports... 

Tags: python, datetime

Have error

```
ValueError: time data '2012-03-15 9:45:00 AM' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

How do convert to datetime? The problem is am/pm, the `%I:%M:%S%p` isn't working for me.

I need the date to add it to `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", (0,0,0,8,56,0,0,0,0))`

**Edit Two: trying to use...**

**

```
import time
from time import strftime
from datetime import date, time, datetime
```

**
These imports in this order cause a problem with

start_time= time.time()

```
start_time = time.time()
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time'
```

old edits......

```
datetime.combine(y='a date',z= 'a time')
```

y is `datetime.date`
z is `datetime.time`

`y=datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day)` this solved.

gives a problem.

z is `datetime.time`

`datetime.combine(y, datetime.time(18, 54, 32)`)

error message.............

```
    a =datetime.combine(y, datetime.time(18, 54, 32))
TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: 2012-03-15 9:45:00 should work. Isn't it a 24 (military time) hour system? Just put 21:45:00 for 9:45 PM.

Comment: You are missing `%` before `Y`, and you need `%I` not `%H`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the update: you have a mess in imports from datetime module. The correct sample is:

```
>>> from datetime import date, time, datetime
>>> d=date(2012,10,01)
>>> t=time(10,11,12)
>>> datetime.combine(d,t)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 10, 11, 12)
```

Comment: I had import hell there was time.time() throwing an error further up the script!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at dateutil package http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

```
from dateutil import parser
date = parser.parse("2012-03-15 9:45:00 AM")
```

Comment: How do you combine dates and times??????

Comment: @Merlin Don't understand your question. Explain please. The stupid answer is "Both date and time are in the same string" :-)

Comment: @Merlin You don't need to combine date and time. In my code you get the result of datetime datatype. Nothing to combine. If you want to extract date or time just use date.date() or date.time().

Comment: In my use case, I need to add a date to given time.

Comment: I posted yet another response. As for me you're messing about quite obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2012-03-15 9:45:00 AM", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 9, 45)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2012-03-15 9:45:00 PM", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 21, 45)
```

Comment: if I want to slice the date and add it to time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", (0,0,0,8,56,0,0,0,0)), what would I do?